# Sallen-Key filter for PT100 RTD measurement

Tags: filter, temperature, rtd, pt100, sallen-key

I am going to build temperature sensing system using PT100 sensor (and later Raspberry PI 3). I refer my work to Microchip note AN687 [Precision Temperature-Sensing With RTD Circuits](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/appnotes/00687c.pdf).
On the page 4 is shown circuit I want to build:
[image]

I am beginner. I have a question: why values of resistors R8, R9, R10 are like they are? I researched some about Sallen-Key filter but didn't find identical circuit. In other words - how values of elements were calculated?

Comment: That is a very bodgy 3rd order low pass sallen key filter that you'll struggle with to find design equations so state what frequency response and DC accuracy you require and maybe someone will help.

Comment: Why this filter is bodgy?

Comment: I am going to read temperature on Raspberry using MCP3008 chip (ADC converter). It's my goal, if it'll no suceedd I will use Adafruit board designed for PT100 usage - https://www.adafruit.com/product/3328

Comment: Isn't just a capacitor enough?

Comment: @GregoryKornblum Obviously the filtered output follows far too slowly the temperature changes if a single capacitor filter is used and it attenuates enough at 50Hz. To reach 0,5 bit accurate settling for 12 bit ADC needs time = 9 * RC time constant.

Comment: What are you measuring? What temperature changes so quickly?

Comment: You should take a giant step backwards, and tell us what sort of temperature system you're trying to control.  It would need to be a pretty special system if you actually need to use a filter like this, and I suspect it isn't.

Comment: I have good quality two PT100 4-wire sensors, each 10 meters long. I am going to build weather station based on Raspberry PI 3. First sensor will be placed 5cm above the ground, the second one about 2 meters. Raspberry PI will be used to send data (Ethernet or GPRS module) to database and, finally to website after every 10 minutes.

Comment: On the other forum I found similar topic and  I suppose that this Microchip note will suit my needs (temperature sensing) , so I started to studying it. Anyway, MAX31865 from Adafruit seems to be good solution too.

Comment: Please look more carefully at the note you linked. The caption of the figure you've reproduced states, "This circuit uses a RTD element to measure temperatures from -200°C to 600°C." Your stated application needs higher resolution (and lower temperature span) than this will produce - like about a factor of 10.

Answer (score 2):

The schematic you found has the lowpass filter schematic drawn wrong:

[image: 3rd-order]

Answer (score 0):

Your linked application note actually tells quite thoroughly the ideas behind the filter, but it's unfortunately engineer's speak to another engineer.

You can simulate the filter. It is at the same time a lowpass filter and an amplifier. The filtering is needed to attenuate all noise that the probe collects from disturbing fields. The component values are selected surely to provide enough attenuation at the most harmful frequencies 50...60Hz and simply to have values that are available. One needs accurate enough resistors, especially R10 and R11 must be ok because they affect the scaling.

3rd degree filter also needs more accurate component values than simpler filters. Bad filter, which attenuates enough at  50 Hz and up,  can cause too long fluctuating output or too slow rise to the right voltage when the temperature changes rapidly (=for example the probe has been put to cold or hot liquid). It surely is a design criteria to get the filtered signal to settle fast enough without too much overshoot.

A part of the needed filtering and the calibration can be made in PIC software. To keep the calibration and programmed filtering valid the component values must stay stable.

**ADD:** The later discussion in comments reveal that you are sensing outdoor air temperature. A simple RC filter surely is enough, because that application can well stand for ex. 15 seconds long settling time.